# How should a UTF-8 $_POST should look on PHPmyAdmin MySql DataBase

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, utf-8

If I POST a string, say "configuración", to a MySql Data Base using UTF-8 charset, how should it look if I explore the data using PHPmyAdmin. 
Like this
1.- configuración
or this
2.- configuraciÃ³n

I am trying to determine this to see if I am using the charset right.
 
If in my database the string is represented in the second form, in a HTML Table it is echoed in a readeable way (configuración). But when I export as .csv using PHP, Excel for Mac opens it in a non readeable way (configuraci?n).
And if in the database is displayed in the first form, in the HTML is represented in a non readable way, but on the .csv export it is displayed as readable text.

Comment: @manniL how is that?

Comment: You can use utf8mb4 value for the table

Comment: Duplicate of "Trouble..."; see in particular 'Test the Data' and 'Mojibake'.  Finally look at 'Fixes' for solutions.